# PHP cURL returns error 52 if Content-Length is set

Tags: php, curl, content-length

I am trying to post a form in a remote website via php cURL.

here is my cURL configuration (I added several explanations in the comments):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $action);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); //without this line the request is being sent with GET method (I can see that with curl_getinfo)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); //$postData is an urlencoded string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Expect:',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'Origin: http://XXX',
    ));
```

After executing such configuration, I receive such response:

```
string(610) "HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://XXX
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: DWS
Content-Length: 15536
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 10:59:35 GMT
X-Varnish: 2567206754
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html
Server: DWS
Content-Length: 357
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 10:59:35 GMT
X-Varnish: 2567207187
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

I tried to add a Content-Length header to the cURL configuration:

```
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData)
```

But then cURL fails with error 52 (Empty reply from server).
In order to make sure that the content length that i am specifying is in fact correct, I tried to add a cus tom string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS (like 'foo=bar'), and set Content-Length: 7, but the result was the same.

I also tried to covert whole code and use Zend 2 Http Client, but with no luck.
I think I've read all other posts about the cURL 52 error, but none of them seemed to have anything in common with Content-Length header, so I hope that someone here might help me out.

Please let me know if you need any more information from my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `POST` request to the URL specified in the `$action` variable returns a HTTP 302 redirect, in which CURL will send the next request using `GET`, see the 2nd paragraph here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L.

You already use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to get around this, but it needs `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` as well, as documented in the **Strings** section here: http://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/

You should not explicitly set the `Content-Length` but have CURL handle that.

Alternatively you could manually "follow" the `Location` header and use the URL from that header in the `$action` variable (it may be useful to try that for testing first).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked! I'm still not able to achieve my goal, but I think it is not related to this thread